# mysql intellisense not working when pressed control + spacebar

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm new to MySQL and its environment and im used to intellisense when working with tables and its attributes...but in mysql i keep getting this error when trying to access some table or attribute.
[image: Buildin:list-members]

i have a database name Lab which contains 3 table ...when i use database Lab and try to use intellisense it gives me that error ... i have tried restarting mysql and laptop but nothing helps but when i drop every table and recreate it...then intellisense starts to work again...

im using mysql 8CE latest version to this date...and mysqlworkbench

[image]

as you can see in the picture when i try to use autocomplete or intellisense it throws that error

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain on which ide you are working. I thought maybe VS code, but that is i a guess

Comment: no vscode is a editor im using mysql's own ide named mysql workbench

Comment: @MohammadAwais as far as my stable version is mysql workbench 6.3.10.

Answer (score 0):

you add the first letter manually, before your strg + space

[image: So you enter t]

But it is still very buggy even in version 8.0,19

[see bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92015)

As is said,it doesn'Ät work at this time. like described in thebugreport.

But when it works again. It works again like before you add after the schea a dot and add a letter. See image

[image]

Comment: can anyone guide me which version of MySQL workbench should i use ? that is stable and doesn't gives this error.

Comment: i have edited the question and placed an imaged doing what you answered but still not good and keep getting the error.

Comment: Lookk thwere is at this time no working intellisense. I described how you can get it  when it was still working. I don't know any version where ir works. Because since Version 8 appeared, it was buggy..